# Return excel file created in servlet as response

Tags: java, jquery, sapui5

I've created excel file using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) and tried to return it as response to ajax call. I want the browser to prompt "save the created file" window.
The problem is that I get gibbrish in the servlet's response and no prompts or whatsoever

I've found similar problems here, on StackOverflow, but the solutions to their issues doesn't work for me (or I miss something).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156481/download-excel-from-servlet) the problem was solved by using html tags, but I can't (as far as I know) use them in SAPUI5.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158004/difficulty-sending-excel-workbook-from-servlet) is a very similar case, which I used for my matter, but it still doesn't work.

Here is the client side code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url : "Export",
            type : "post",
            mimeType: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            success : function(){
                console.log("data was exported successfully");
            },
            error: function(){
                
                console.log("error while exporting data");
            },
            complete: function(){
                console.log("exporting data has been completed");
            }
        });
```

And here is the servlet's code:

```
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ReportsData.xls");
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    workbook.write(out); 
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

The file is created from a database 'select' wuery result set in a `while(result.next())` loop.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like your ajax call is the problem.  Maybe you can link directly to your servlet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using ajax try making a call like this in javascript.

```
window.open(("urltoyourservlet"), "_blank");
```

This will open a new window linking directly to your servlet.  Then the browser should automatically handle handle downloading the excel file based on the mime/type.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works well and it totally fits my purpose.

Comment: What? Doesn't this turn into a GET request at whatever endpoint then? What about a data payload that needs to get sent with the POST?

Comment: @radicalmatt the user didn't need a `post` request in this case...Read the question and u will see.